# The app could not be located

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics

i integrated crashlytics into my unity game, everything worked fine, but then  i had to change my package name and my working mail, since then whenever i open the dashboard it gives me an alert "Sorry the app could not be located".
I reinstalled the crashlytics sdk in unity, used new login in prepare fabric tab, but the issue is still there, although the crashlytics seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Usually this means we aren't detecting the build and run event. Please make sure you are building and running in the relevant IDE. Also, clean your app and dependencies in the native IDE to make sure the bundle ID is updated in all locartions. If you still run into issues, you will need to contact support as your app may be in a weird state in our system.